# Multiprocessing Scipy optimization in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to run an optimization problem in parallel. The code works well when not in parallel but I struggle to add the multiprocessing layer to it. It's a sort of a vectorized MLE estimation, but I wrote a much simpler code below featuring the same error.

```
from scipy import optimize
import multiprocessing as mp

# function 'func' to be minimized (with a number of argument>2)
def func(x, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    
    x = x*x + arg1*x + arg2*x + arg3*x
    
    return x

# function 'fit' that is called to minimize function 'func'
def fit(func, arguments):
    
    x0, arg1, arg2, arg3 = arguments

    results = optimize.minimize(func, x0,  args=(arg1, arg2, arg3), method='BFGS')
    
    print(f'value of the function at the minimum: {results.fun}')
    print(f'value of the parameter x when the function is at the minimum: {results.x}')
    
    return results

# main code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Arbitrary values of the parameters
    x0=100
    arg1=1
    arg2=2
    arg3=3
    
    # gather in a tuple
    arguments=(x0, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    
    # if not run with multiprocessing:
    #fit(func, arguments)

    # multiprocessing
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.map(fit,arguments)
```

The error I get is:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 358, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'fit' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Another thing I am trying to do is to see at each iteration of the minimization problem the values of `results.fun` and `results.x` to know where the algorithm is. I've understood that this is done through callback functions, however I've seen that these can be used with a `pool.apply_async` function and I'm not sure that it would work for a maximum likelihood estimation problem.

For reference, I'm on Windows and Python 3.8.10

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now to test the multiprocessing, but for observing the progress, have you tried `scipy.optimize.minimize(..., options={"disp":True})`?

Comment: I ran your code and did not get the same error, though I did have to adjust the code to get it to run for me.

Comment: you minimally need to re-work `arguments` and change `fit` to take a single argument. (map only supports functions taking a single argument). The single argument can itself be a tuple which you unpack within the function.

Comment: That's what I had to do to get Jessica's code working. I added the function to `arguments` and then changed the `fit` function signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing arguments to a **tuple packed inside a list** and it works like a charm !

```
arguments= [(x0, arg1, arg2, arg3)]
```

Take care and stay classy ma chère !

Comment: Thanks Shankar. This now works if I try on Noteable.io but not on my laptop. It's weird, I'm trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. This works on Pycharm. It seems to be a Spyder version issue!!

```
from scipy import optimize
import multiprocessing as mp

# function 'func' to be minimized (with a number of argument>2)

def func(x, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    
    x = x*x + arg1*x + arg2*x + arg3*x

    return x

# function 'fit' that is called to minimize function 'func'
def fit(arguments):
    
    x0, arg1, arg2, arg3 = arguments
    
    results = optimize.minimize(func, x0,  args=(arg1, arg2, arg3), method='BFGS', options={"disp":True})
    
    print(f'value of the function at the minimum: {results.fun}')
    print(f'value of the parameter x when the function is at the minimum: {results.x}')
    
    return results

# main code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Arbitrary values of the parameters
    x0=100
    arg1=1
    arg2=2
    arg3=3
    
    # if not run with multiprocessing:
    # arguments= (x0, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    # fit(arguments)

    # multiprocessing
    arguments= [(x0, arg1, arg2, arg3)]
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.map(fit,arguments)
```